# Implement collision detection for scoring on a javascript "catch" game

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

I'm working on a very simple JS game using canvas but I'm having a really hard time implementing the collision detection for scoring points.

The game is a catch game, so, every time the player controlled block on the bottom of the screen hits one of the falling balls, the score count should be updated by one. I've looked online for many different ways to do this but no luck so far.

The game has three different objects, Ball, Player and Score, each one with its own draw and update functions. The most recent way I've been trying to implement the collision detection in by putting it inside the Score's update function but to no avail.

How would you go about doing this?

Here's the code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const c = canvas.getContext('2d')

canvas.width = 500
canvas.height = 800

//Variables

//keyboard events
let leftPressed = false
let rightPressed = false
//ball
let moveSpeed = 5
let balls = []
//player
let player
let pWidth = 60
let pHeight = 20
let color = 'black'
//score
let score
let x = canvas.width / 1.5
let y = 30
let points = 0


//Event listeners

//move
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = true;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = true;
  }
}

//stop
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyUpHandler(e) {
  if (e.key == "Right" || e.key == "ArrowRight") {
    rightPressed = false;
  } else if (e.key == "Left" || e.key == "ArrowLeft") {
    leftPressed = false;
  }
}

//Objects
function Ball(x, y, dy, radius, color) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.dy = dy
  this.radius = radius
  this.color = color

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false)
    c.strokeStyle = 'black'
    c.stroke()
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fill()
    c.closePath()
  }

  this.update = function() {
    this.y += dy
    this.draw()
  }

}

function Player(x, y, pWidth, pHeight, color) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.pWidth = pWidth
  this.pHeight = pHeight
  this.color = color

  this.draw = function() {
    c.fillStyle = this.color
    c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.pWidth, this.pHeight)

  }

  this.update = function() {
    //move player

    if (leftPressed && this.x > 0) {
      this.x -= moveSpeed
    } else if (rightPressed && this.x < canvas.width - pWidth) {
      this.x += moveSpeed
    }

    this.draw()
  }
}

function Score(x, y, points) {
  this.x = x
  this.y = y
  this.points = 0

  this.draw = function() {
    c.font = '30px Helvetica'
    c.fillStyle = '#000'
    c.fillText(points, this.x, this.y)
  }

  this.update = function() {
    if (balls.x >= player.x && balls.x + balls.radius <= player.x + player.pWidth) {
      this.points += 1
    }
    this.draw()
  }
}


// Initialize
function init() {
  //Initialize balls
  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    let x = Math.random() * canvas.width
    let y = Math.random() * canvas.height
    let dy = 3
    let radius = 15
    let color = 'purple'

    balls.push(new Ball(x, y, dy, radius, color))
  }

  //Initialize player
  player = new Player((canvas.width / 2) - (pWidth / 2),
    canvas.height - pHeight,
    pWidth,
    pHeight,
    color)

  //Initialize score
  score = new Score(x, y, 'Score: ' + points)
}

// Animate
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

  for (i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].update()
  }

  player.update()

  score.update()


}

init()
animate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd likely want to do the collision detection somewhere in your main loop that has access to all your collidable objects.  Assuming only balls and player collide, then in the loop with balls is a good candidate.  Depending on what kind of collision you want, create a function that takes a ball object and compares it to the player.  The simplest hit detection is simple distance based on size/radius of each object, but other more advanced ways exists.

```js
// Animate
function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].update();
    if (detectHit(ball[i], player)) {
      // hit was detected, do stuff
    }
  }

  player.update();
  score.update();
}

function detectHit(ball, player) {
  const ballRadius = ball.radius;
  const ballCenter = {x: ball.x, y: ball.y};
  
  const playerRadius = Math.min(player.pWidth, player.pHeight);
  const playerCenter = {
    x: player.x + player.pWidth / 2,
    y: player.y + player.pHeight / 2
  };
  
  // distance = sqr((x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2)
  const distanceSqrd = (ballCenter.x - playerCenter.x) ** 2 + (ballCenter.y - playerCenter.y) ** 2;
  const radiusDistanceSqrd = (ballRadius + playerRadius) ** 2;
  
  /*
    Instead of getting the square root, save a complex 
    calculation by comparing the squared distances directly
  */
  return distanceSqrd <= radiusDistanceSqrd;
}

const balls = [
  {
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    radius: 5
  },
  {
    x: 50,
    y: 10,
    radius: 5
  },
];

const player = {
  x: 20,
  y: 10,
  pWidth: 15,
  pHeight: 15,
};

balls.forEach(ball => console.log('Hit detected: ', detectHit(ball, player)));
```